# Error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Tags: c++, vector, struct, set

Why am I getting the error at the last two lines? The goal is to find the object in a set, and modify its content.

```
using namespace std;

struct mystruct {
  int id;
  vector<int> y;
  mystruct(const int id):id(id) {}
  bool operator<(const mystruct& x) const { return id < x.id; }
  bool operator==(const mystruct& x) const { return id == x.id; }
};

void test() {
  std::set<mystruct> sx;
  mystruct x(1);
  x.y.push_back(1); x.y.push_back(2);
  sx.insert(x);
  //
  set<mystruct>::iterator i = sx.find(1);
  const mystruct* x1 = &(*i);
  const mystruct x2 = *x1;
  cout << &(i->y) << endl;
  cout << &(x1->y) << endl;
  cout << x2.id << endl;
  x2.y.push_back(3);
  i->y.push_back(4);
}
```

It seems like the iterator returns a constant object, and doesn't let me use `push_back()` to modify the vector `y`. How can I overcome this?

**Error:**

```
test.cpp:27:8: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
  x2.y.push_back(z);
  ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-6.0/include/c++/v1/vector:688:36: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const vector<int>', but method is not marked const
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
                                   ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-6.0/include/c++/v1/vector:691:36: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const vector<int>', but method is not marked const
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(value_type&& __x);
                                   ^
```

Comment: Why `x2` is `const`? You can't modify on it.

Comment: @songyuanyao thank you. You are right. I've to define "const mystruct* x1 = &(*i);" because RHS is "const mytruct *". Hence, I thought I should define x2 as const. But even If I define x2 as not const, I can not modify original x.y vector. x2 is somehow a copy of x1. I think that's the main problem.

Comment: I think I've to change the question :/

Comment: @Sezen Maybe you should go over your design again.  It's your program, and you solely put the `const`-ness in it.  So honestly, you should be the one that would know how to overcome the problem.

Comment: You may need to reconsider the design. Note that the elements put in `set` can't be modifed; the element got from `set::iterator` is const qualified.

Comment: @songyuanyao This is the answer that I'm looking for. Thanks all.

Comment: You probably want `std::map<int, std::vector<int>> sx` instead of the `std::set<mystruct>`, if you intend to associate `int`s with `std::vector<int>`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you cannot modify `x2` is that it is declared `const`, as has been pointed out by @dasblinkenlight. @songyuanyao's comment is right as for accessed to the object referenced by the iterator, but doesn't quite answer the question because it does not say *why* set iterators only allow `const` access.

The reason for this is that, as you know, a `std::set` is an ordered container whose structure is determined by comparing entries to one another using (by default) `operator <`. This means that there is a container *invariant* such that if an item `a` precedes another item `b` in the `std::set`, it follows that `!(b < a)`. I put it like this because this also holds for `std::multiset`. Since, in a set, duplicates are not allowed, it follows that, actually, if `a` precedes `b`, then `a < b`. If this invariant were to be violated, then any set operation that requires the set to be sorted, such as `find` or `insert`, will have unexpected (to be precise, undefined) behavior.

Therefore, a `std::set` will not allow you to change an item using an `iterator`, because you could unwittingly change members of the item in a way that affect its proper place in the set, breaking the invariant and thereby causing undefined behavior.

Unfortunately, the compiler is not smart enough to understand that your comparison function only evaluates certain members, in this case, only `id`. If compiler and language were capable of analyzing and expressing this, they might figure that while `i->id` should be a reference to `const`, `i->m` for any other member `m` could safely be a reference to non-`const`.

There are at least four possible solutions to your problem:

1. The easiest but ugliest solution is to mark the members that you need to modify as `mutable`. Note that you must yourself ensure that changing them does not affect the sort order.
2. Another fairly ugly solution is the deliberate use of `const_cast` as in `const_cast<mystruct &>(*i)` where `i` is an iterator. Again, never change a member that has an effect on the sort order in this way.
3. A more elegant solution that, however, has additional run time overhead, is to add a level of pointer indirection (e.g. using `std::unique_ptr`) to properties that you want to modify. Note, however, that if you were to use the *pointee* in your comparison function, you would still run the risk of breaking the set invariant, only now the compiler and library will no longer prevent you from doing so!
4. The only way that works even *if* you want to change members affecting the sort order is to make a copy of the item, modify the copy, erase the old item, and then re-insert the copy. This allows the container to insert the copy at a *different* position if necessary.

Final notes:

- A hashed container such as `std::unordered_set` will have exactly the same issue, only in this case it is not the comparison function, but both the hash and equality functions that you have to consider.
- For the given reasons, a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` may be a better match for your problem domain, as, in this case, the library knows that the `mapped_type` is not used to determine container structure. Note also how the `value_type` of a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` is `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` instead of `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` exactly for the same reason that changing the key could break the container invariants.

Comment: Thanks for long explanation Arne. I had tried to mark the vector as _mutable_. Then the error went off but it still creates copy of the object and does not let to modify the original vector. Hence, I decided go with _map_ (your last recommendation). I'm not a C++ guru but trying to learn a bit trial and error :). I believe this question also will help a lot of people like me around, because I didn't find an exact post around points to a problem like this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Since `x2` is declared with a `const` qualifier, i.e. `const mystruct x2`, C++ compiler considers only `const`-qualified member functions for all invocations on `x2` and any of its members. In particular, it is looking for `void push_back (const int& val) const` member function to invoke. Obviously, there is no such function, because `push_back` must modify the container, so the compiler produces an error explaining exactly what's going on:

> candidate function not viable: `'this'` argument has type `'const vector<int>'`, but method is not marked `const`

The only way to address this in your code is to remove `const` qualifier from `x2`'s declaration.

Comment: This is complement of @songyuanyao's comment. Thanks.